# Monotone convergence theorem for functions on a discrete set

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

If I have a sequence and it is monotone I can apply the Monotone convergence Theorem [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) to determine if the limit is its supremum or infimum.
If I have a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ I can apply a generalization of theorem to functions [2](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Monotone_Real_Function/Increasing) and I will find the supremum and infimum at $\pm \infty$.
If I have $a_k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, so a in terms of a sequence I ca say $b_n=a_{-n}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then

$1)$ I can think to apply the Monotone convergence theorem to $b_n$ since is a sequence.

$2)$ If $a_k$ is not seen as $b_n$, then it is not a sequence but I can say it as a function on a discrete set, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$. **Question:** Here the monotone theorem still holds?

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem for functions $f:D\to\Bbb R$ (about $\lim_af$ where $a$ is a limit point of $D$) is valid whatever the domain $D\subset\Bbb R.$

Comment: Does not hold only if the domain is an interval? If D is an union of two interval how can I find sup and inf? I mean with which limit?

Comment: It holds for any $D$ and $a$ like in my previous comment.. And it does not tell you the sup and inf on D but e.g. if $f$ is non-decreasing and $a$ is a limit point of $E:=D\cap(-\infty,a),$ it tells you that $\sup f(E)=\lim_{a^-}f,$ in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#More_general_subsets